# Can not authenticate/sign in user ASP.Net Core 6 Identity. Why?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to implement ASP.NET Core identity authentication / authorization in my web app.

- ASP.NET Core 6 MVC
- Entity Framework Core
- ASP.NET Core Identity

I am seeding database with Users data:

```
public class User: IdentityUser<long>
```

After creating list of users I am making some actions on it related to `IdentityUser`:

```
    PasswordHasher<User> ph = new PasswordHasher<User>();
    Users.ForEach(c => c.PasswordHash = ph.HashPassword(c, c.PasswordHash));
    Users.ForEach(c => c.NormalizedEmail = c.Email.ToUpper());
    Users.ForEach(c=>c.NormalizedUserName=c.UserName.ToUpper());
    Users.ForEach(c => c.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
    Users.ForEach(c => c.ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"));
```

Seeding:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(PatientMockDB.Users);
```

My program file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string connString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ADbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connString);
});



builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<long>>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;

})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole<long>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ADbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<I1Repository, AsklepiosDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<I2Repository, AsklepiosDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<I3Repository, AsklepiosDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<I4Repository, AsklepiosDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<I5Repository, AsklepiosDbContext>();

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});


builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/HomeArea/Home/Denied";
    options.Cookie.Name = "mycookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.LoginPath = "/HomeArea/Home/Login";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options => options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/HomeArea/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();


app.UseRouting();

app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("areas", "{area:exists}/{controller:exists}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{area=HomeArea}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And the login method, I have tried multiple ways, logging with username, logging with user e-mail, logging with password, logging with hashed password, unfortunatelly I always receive failed result...

What am I doing in wrong way? How make it working?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogInEmployee(LogInViewModel model)
{
    if (model==null)
    {
        return View("LogIn", model);
    }
    long userId = model.User.Id;
    model.User.UserType = Core.Enums.UserType.Employee;
    User user = _context.CheckEmailAndRole(model.User);

    if (user != null)
    {
        TempData["User"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);

        var result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.User.PasswordHash,false,false);
        result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Email, model.User.PasswordHash, false, false);
        result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, user.PasswordHash, false, false);
        result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Email, user.PasswordHash, false, false);
        result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, user.PasswordHash, false, false);
        result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.User.PasswordHash, false, false);
        SignInResult signInResult = await _signManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, model.User.PasswordHash, false);
        signInResult = await _signManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, user.PasswordHash, false);
        bool lol=await _signManager.CanSignInAsync(user);
        await _signManager.SignInAsync(user, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
       //something
            }
        }
    }               
    else
    {
        
    }
    model.LogInFailed = true;
    return View("LogIn", model);
}
```

model.User.PasswordHash -> non-hashed version of password, provided by user

```
public class ADbContext : IdentityDbContext<User,IdentityRole<long>,long>, I1Repository, I2Repository, I3Repository, I4Repository, I5Repository
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, you have one big problem... You shouldn't be using `PasswordHasher`! Get everything working as described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity). If it works, add things that you think you need to fulfil the requirements - and see where you are getting an error. Unless you are doing something *very* advanced - you should never access Identity objects through LINQ statement; only through Identity APIs

Second (but related) - what is the purpose of generic in `IdentityUser<long>`? What's wrong with default `Guid` type? Again, if you need it - fine; but first make it work in the way most similar to how Microsoft instructs you before making changes.

Finally, it is not clear, what is the purpose of these Ix repositories. Are they relevant to Identity? If not - please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I will go trough documentation. 

I am using IdentityUser<long>, because this is my first little bigger (than some basic tutorial app) web app and I started adding Identity after creating all models, dbcontext, logic etc. And originally my Ids were of type long . Using guid will require some additional work from me, but hm.. probably less than I've already done to make it work this way.

Those repositories should not have any direct impact on my issue with Identity. But, I saw others people having different issues, because for example they were adding services in wrong order.

Comment: "Using guid will require some additional work from me" - that means that you are doing something wrong. If you use Identity APIs, the type of the key is totally transparent to your code.

Comment: adding services can be in any order. *Using* service in `app.UseXXX()` order matters. In general, don't worry about problems other people are having! You will have enough problems of your own ;)